# Is there a global setting for number form

Tags: number-representation, librarylink

I'm creating strings which represent equations in C to use with library link. The problem I have is that numbers in `ScientificForm` are no longer useful after they are converted to strings. For example, `2.77778*10^11` becomes

```
          11
2.77778 10
```

So is there a way to make mathematica globally treat all numbers as standard form (i.e. non-scientific form)?

Comment: Is `NumberForm[yourNumber, {\[Infinity], 6}, ExponentStep -> \[Infinity]]` what you are looking for?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:  I believe he wants a *GLOBAL* setting, like `SetOptions[]` so he doesn't have to convert each and every single number in a notebook.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork on the other hand he is creating strings from the numbers therefore he has code converting the global numbers to strings in which case he just needs to use `NumberForm` in his code

Comment: ...to continue, rather than think of the problem as converting your numbers globally and then converting to strings why not make the reformatting part of your string conversion and leave the numbers as they are in the notebook?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch:  I'll let the OP answer, but I can imagine that in a notebook that will Export lots of different numerical results to different files, one would want a global option assignment to specify the form of the numbers (even converting to Strings), much like a global SetOption assignment, for instance that all Graphics should use Italic font, etc.  One *could* hand code the option specification into every graphical computation, but a global SetOption is far simpler.  It also means that if he wants instead to get traditional numerical output (for MMa), he need change only the Option.

Comment: Mike, that is what i'm currently doing and you're right i could add that to all of my code. the only problem is I'm working with a large number of variables so adding that line to each one will make the code huge and cluttered. David is right, what i was asking about was a global option.

So the basis is that I'm converting these numbers to strings which are then directly processed by a compiler, and C has no inherent capability for processing exponentials so treating all numbers as non-scientific allows C to work with them as doubles. 

It seems like the easiest way is to spam mikes line.

Comment: Have you tried CForm? It gives `2.77778e11`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I had but i'm not using the symbolic C functionality.

Comment: Actually im being silly i can just have a function like `sF[x_] := NumberForm[x, Infinity, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]` and then i can use that without the code getting to ridiculous.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. You say you are converting to string so my point is why not simply add the number formatting as part of this. By definition it will not require any additional work. If that is not the case then can you explain how you convert tot strings?

Comment: regarding your comment "actually I'm being silly ..." that is what I was suggesting but what you appeared to reject above???

Comment: @NicholasGaffney-Henderson This function just give you a string which is a valid number in C ... I don't understand your comment about not using SymbolicC stuff.   Can you explain why you can't use the output of CForm?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch sorry i haven't explained my situation very well, the formatting of the string needs to be very particular and the code generating the string is quite cluttered already, i understood your suggestion to be adding the line `NumberForm[yourNumber, {\[Infinity], 6}, ExponentStep -> \[Infinity]]` to every variable which would increase the size of the code substantially making it more difficult to work on. A short example of my code could be like this `ToString[sF[edgeArea[[node, 1]]]] <> 
  " * pressureF(interpolate(t,data), interpolate(t,data2) - \
pressureF(x["`

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but for me giving an answer is providing the recipe and ingredients. I don't see it as my job to cook the meal and chew the food. In other words those asking the question need to think about the task as well. You already have code that converts your numbers to strings but you simply want to change how the numbers look. So the point is that you simply replace `ToString` in your code with your new string conversion function, lets call it `myString`. I don't see that has being a difficult or lengthy task. See edited answer if in doubt

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh my mistake i thought CForm was part of SymbolicC. That certainly would work in that case but it has the same problem as using NumberForm in that it would add bulk to the code.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Thats fair enough, but its not what i understood you to be suggesting.

Comment: ...solely because you had not shown us how you were converting to strings, what your code was etc. So we, as people trying to help you, are flying blind. Which is why I suggested some of this has to be left to the person asking the question to figure out, but in any case since you have posted your code in the comment above the solution is now explicit in my answer.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Okay so i wasn't as specific as you would like, but my question was not about the string generation originally it was about the representation of numbers gobally, so your suggestion, while correct, was not what i was looking for, indeed it was what i was trying to avoid.

Comment: We are going in circles but if you re-read my comments and answer the thrust is that you can implement this without any additional work and without the need to find a global option which, stand corrected, you will find elusive. In other words you get the result you need with minimal effort. The alternative is to say no global option exists and leave you to figure out the rest.

Comment: Going in circles indeed. Yes you did present a good alternative to what i was asking, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are converting numbers to strings you presumably have some code for doing this? Since you are not globally converting numbers to strings via an option setting you still require the string conversion step in your process. Therefore why not just make the reformatting of your number part of this code?

I think something like this may be what you need. I use similar when exporting numbers to XML.

```
ToString@NumberForm[2.77778*10^11, {\[Infinity], 6},ExponentStep -> \[Infinity]]
```

So rather than apply e.g. `ToString[#]&/@numbers` in your code change it to e.g.

```
ToString@NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 6},ExponentStep -> \[Infinity]]&/@numbers
```

**Edit**

Now that we can see how you are doing the string conversion just make a function `myString`

```
myString=ToString@NumberForm[#, {\[Infinity], 6},ExponentStep -> \[Infinity]]&
```

Now simply do a find and replace in your code, Find `ToString`, replace with `myString`

Answer (score 2):

The two-line formatting you quote in your question is the result of string conversion into [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm.html), which is the default [`FormatType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormatType.html) of [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html).  If you use `CForm` you get something more useful for C:

```
ToString[2.77778*10^11, CForm]
```

> ```
> "2.77778e11"
> ```

You can change the default `FormatType` with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html):

```
SetOptions[ToString, FormatType -> CForm];
```

Now:

```
ToString[2.77778*10^11]
```

> ```
> "2.77778e11"
> ```

Since you did not state the method that you use for conversion to strings it is difficult to recommend anything more specific.

Comment: my reading of the question was that he wants no exponents

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Oops.

Answer (score 1):

```
$PrePrint = NumberForm[#, ExponentFunction -> (Null&)] &
```

`$PrePrint` is a function that is applied to every expression before display; in this case, we simply use `NumberForm` to format all numbers in the expression with no exponent.